# Node Js and MongoDB Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/node";
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database Connected!");
  db.close();
});
```

I cannot connect with mongoDB. The output is:
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`